# Error running forever.js on Windows - "'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, node-modules, forever

I am trying to run `forever.js` via the Windows command prompt and I get the following output:

`>npm i -g forever`

`/my-project>forever start index.js`

*Log output:*

`'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`

I think it's something to do with the `PATH` that `forever` is using for the `node` binary, but I don't know how to fix it...

*EDIT:* Forever is using the following command (which is surrounded by quotes `" "`):

`"C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"`

Comment: looks like you need quotes around it or to escape spaces in the path

Comment: How do I do that in forever?

Answer (score 1):

If you type `dir /x` in the root of c:, you can see the [short name](https://web.archive.org/web/20190807225855/https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir) of the directory.

So, try the following instead:

```
C:\PROGRA~1\nodejs\node.exe
```

[image: dir /x example]

Answer (score 0):

installing forever version 1.0.0  solved the problem for me

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem with forever 2.0.0.

I use a workaround in "forever.js":  (I start my app by "node forever.js" )

```
const configChild = {
    //
    // Basic configuration options
    //
    silent: true,    // Silences the output from stdout and stderr in the parent process
    'killTree': true, // Kills the entire child process tree on `exit`
    ....
}

// =======================================================
// **Workaround for Windows** 
// =======================================================
if (process.platform === 'win32' && process.execPath == "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe") {
    configChild.command = '"C:\\PROGRA~1\\nodejs\\node.exe"';
}

const child = new (forever.Monitor)('app.js', configChild);

....

child.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

That reason is space in "C:Program files...".  Batch divide command based space, so that understand "C:Program" is command.

I think you run that command not in C drive, right? I don't know why, if run command not in C drive, path in environment variable is recognized not one string.

If show same error, refer to next

```
ECHO OFF
SET node="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node"
SET forever="%APPDATA%\npm\node_modules\forever\bin\forever"
%node% %forever% start index.js
```